# Php HTML input/output code not working

Tags: php

I am trying to make a php program where the user inputs how he wants his text to look and what size it is, but there is a problem with code.

Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Input</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="output.php">
<p>
    What would you like to say?
    <input type="text" name="text">     
</p>

<p>Enter your font choice:
<select name="font">
    <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>Enter your font size:
<select name="size">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>    
    </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="Sumbit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

And in output.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['font'] = $_POST['font'];
    $_SESSION['size'] = $_POST['size'];
    $_SESSION['text'] = $_POST['text'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Output</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    echo "<font size='$_POST['size']' 
          face='$_POST['font']>'$_POST['text']</font>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much, I'm new to php btw.

Comment: And _what_ problem is there with the code? Or is this meant to be a guessing game?

Comment: using `<font>` is around a decade out of date

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve]

Comment: 1997 here I come!!!!

Comment: @Martin `<marquee><blink>Burn my eyeballs</blink></marquee>`

Comment: @arkascha I wonder if there's a dupe for guessing games?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, Ill make sure to state the problem, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks wrong (The closing single quote for face is at the wrong position):

```
<?php 
    echo "<font size='$_POST['size']' 
          face='$_POST['font']>'$_POST['text']</font>";
?>
```

It should be something like this:

```
<?php 
    echo "<font size='{$_POST['size']}' 
          face='{$_POST['font']}'>{$_POST['text']}</font>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, as far as I remember, an HTML tag `font` so the following line is wrong. The use of single quotes also looked incorrect ~ there is a closing single quote after the end tag `>`

```
echo "<font size='$_POST['size']' 
      face='$_POST['font']>'$_POST['text']</font>";
```

I would think that perhaps you would want to use the inline `style` attribute for some element, such as:

```
echo "<p style='font-family:{$_SESSION['font']};size:{$_SESSION['size']}'>{$_POST['text']}</p>";
```

[Note: using curly braces, as above, within a quoted string - where the quotes are double, not single - allows you to reference variables/objects/arrays etc that you would normally need to escape prior to use.]

My memory is not what it was once upon a time but I accept that there is ( WAS ) an HTML tag `font` - however it is obsolete and [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers,
>   its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to
>   avoid using it.

Comment: Possibly helpful to the OP to explain the syntax you're using of `{$var}`